# Конфликтует bootstrap и jquery (ajax), что делать?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, bootstrap, laravel

В общем такая вот ситуация:
Есть файл welcome.blade.php  в котором написаны скрипт jquery, который ajax-ом подгружает страницы и в меню должны подсвечивать красным цветом выбранные. Подключена библиотека бутстрап, которая дает возможность сайту сворачиваться по блокам как нужно. Но беда в том, что при подключении бутстрапа - ajax-выделение красным цветом в подменю НЕ работает, но если отключить библиотеку бутстрапа, то все выделяется и подсвечивает... Подскажите как быть в такой ситуации... Где я что не так сделал или не учел?
файл header_style.css:

```
.activeEv{
color: red !important; /* Цвет активной ссылки */
}
```

файл welcome.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="bootstrap-3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>  <!-- Если убрать эту строку, то .activeEv срабатывает -->
   <!--
    <link href="../../public/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!-- Если поставить эту строку вместо предыдущей, бутстрап НЕ работает, а .activeEv срабатывает-->
    -->
    <link href="bootstrap-3/css/header_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
@include('header')

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container ">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav centermenu">
                            <li  class="loadBtn"><a name="top"> languages </a></li>
                            <li  class="loadBtn"><a> targets      </a></li>
                            <li  class="loadBtn"><a> bd           </a></li>
                            <li  class="loadBtn"><a> instruction  </a></li>
                            <li  class="loadBtn"><a> cooperation  </a></li>
                        </ul>
</div></div></div></div></div>

<div class="container">
    <div id="content"><a></a> </div>
</div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var tpls = ['languages.blade.php', 'targets.blade.php',  'bd.blade.php', 'instruction.blade.php', 'cooperation.blade.php'];

                $('.loadBtn').click(function(){
                    $('.loadBtn').removeClass('activeEv');
                    $(this).addClass('activeEv');
                    loadContent($(this).index());
                });
                loadContent(0);

                function loadContent(index) {
                    if (!tpls[index]) return;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: tpls[index],
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html){
                            $("#content").html(html);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </div>

@include('footer')

<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="bootstrap-3/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
```

Изменил подключение библиотек в файле welcome.blade.php:

```
   <!--
    <link href="../../public/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    -->
```

Comment: Бутстрап перебивает стили для элемента? .activeEv{color: red !important;}

Comment: попробовал....не сработало.....

Comment: @Александр После клика в консольке что-нибудь есть?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2017:09:28:40 +0300] "GET /cooperation.blade.php?_=1491373696676 HTTP/1.1" 200 945 "http://languagecards.org/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"   двухсотая, запрос нормально отрабатывает...

Comment: Ожидался конец значения, но найдено «\9 ».  Ошибка при парсинге значения «background-color».  Потерянное объявление.  bootstrap.css:6408:25   - консоль браузера

Answer (score 3):

Проверьте, 
у вас подключено !3 библиотеки jQuery в примере, все разных версий. 
app.js от laravel уже содержит минифицированую библиотеку jQuery.
bootstrap.js тоже использует jQuery для своих скриптов но как отдельно стоящую, и, тут нужно выбрать что то одно или app.js от laravel, или bootstrap.js + jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Я тоже столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой, используйте встроенный css и js от laravel, app.js(ajax и bootstrap.js) и app.css(bootstrap.css).

Comment: app.css еслим подключить вместо bootstrap.css, то бутстрап не работает....